# PyTesseract FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\...........\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_467d8rol.osd'

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

Using PyTesseract method `pytesseract.image_to_osd` I find the error quoted before:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'D:\...........\AppData\Local\Temp\tess_467d8rol.osd'

This is the code I am using:

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", type=str, default="img.png",
    help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image and show it
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
cv2.imshow("Original", image)

# Here, I can have the info that I want
# In this case I want to know if my image is rotated, if so, what is the angle of rotation. 
results = pytesseract.image_to_osd(image, output_type=Output.DICT, config="--psm 4 --dpi 300")
print(results)

# use our imutils function to rotate an image 180 degrees
rotated = imutils.rotate(image, 180)
cv2.imshow("Rotated by 180 Degrees", rotated)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

***Just to notice that if I do not use the configuration of "--dpi 300" I receive the following error as well:***

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError:
> (1, 'UZN file D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\AppData\Local\Temp\tess_l9s298s0 loaded.

> Estimating resolution as 295 UZN file
> D:\Usuarios\wrodriguez\AppData\Local\Temp\tess_l9s298s0 loaded.

> Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Too few
> characters. Skipping this page Error during processing.')

**NOTE:**
These are the versions I am using:

- `python` = "^3.10"
- `pytesseract` = "^0.3.9"
- `imutils` = "^0.5.4"
- `opencv-contrib-python` = "^4.6.0"
- `opencv-python` = "^4.6.0"

Why am I using both `opencv-contrib-python` and `opencv-pyhon`? Because it is still not clear to me what are the differences between them. And the problem is not there, even though I am sure that using both is not correct.

Comment: `opencv-contrib-python` has *contrib* modules _additionally_. both have the base modules.